# WDS suddenly not adding new Windows 7 Install Images to the domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, unattended, wds, answer-file

I recently setup a WDS role on my Server 2008 R2 domain controller.  For the last week I've been planning and testing a Windows 7 Professional deployment.  I built a machine with Windows 7 and installed all my programs needed on it.  I created all the Install and Boot images I needed in WDS, then sysprepped the Windows 7 installation and captured it using a Capture boot image.

My first test deploy worked great and it automatically added the newly imaged machine to my domain.  However I wanted to add more automation to it and started making an unattended.xml and oobeunattend.xml file, configuring it with disk prepping and product keys, etc...

After testing my unattended files and getting them to my satisfaction, I ran another test deployment.  Everyone worked great except for it didn't add the machine to the domain automatically.  I'm not sure if this was something I did in my unattended files or if since I'm using unattended files will I now have to add this inside the unattended files themselves.

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Under my OOBEunatteded.xml file I was able to add the UnattendedJoin component to the specialize and it worked.